# How do I uninstall MultiROM?

Tags: rom, uninstallation

I have a rooted Nexus 4 with stock Android on it.  I decided to try out the MultiROM app on the play store.  I am now trying to uninstall it, however the MultiROM app does two things:

1. It installs a recovery called TWRP
2. It adds a 'boot' menu which lets you select between the OSes

I was able to undo #1 by reinstalling ClockWorkMod ROM.

However, every time I boot up, the OS selection screen still appears.  Note that the OS selection screen only has 'internal' on it.

How can I remove this selection screen and remove MultiROM completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flash the original / stock ROM for your phone. But first, make sure to clear data / factory reset, wipe cache, and clear dalvik cache.

Comment: Do you mean the [stock images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) here? Will doing that unroot the device?

Comment: @Shah That link seems right. And yes, flashing stock ROM will unroot your device. You'll have to root it again. But this process will definitely remove multiROM.

Answer (score 3):

**Uninstalling MultiROM** - Source [AddictiveTips](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/dual-boot-android-ubuntu-touch-or-firefox-os-on-nexus-4-7-with-multirom/)

The developers have provided an easy way to get rid of MultiROM and get things back to the way they were before. All you have to do is flash the appropriate MultiROM uninstaller file for your device from recovery, and MultiROM will be removed from your device. Do note that this will also remove all secondary ROMs that you may have installed.

[MultiROM Uninstaller for Nexus 4](http://d-h.st/uVZ)
[MultiROM Uninstaller for Nexus 7 (2012)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ycrwdcva8gdnghn/multirom_uninstaller-2.zip)
[MultiROM Uninstaller for Nexus 7 (2013)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xfg9ic1x54taqam/multirom_uninstaller-flo-2.zip)

The MultiROM-modified TWRP recovery will still remain on your device, but that shouldn’t be an issue; you can simply ignore the `Advanced > MultiROM` submenu, and use the rest of the recovery as the regular TWRP. Though if you want to remove that as well, you can easily [flash a recovery of your choice](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-a-custom-recovery-to-an-android-phone-device/).

Comment: Note: the first file (for Nexus 4) is hosted in a site with links leading to .exe versions of the ZIP file, so be extra careful and make sure to click the right link (fake "Download" links abound) to obtain the .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy.. you should go to TWRP recovery >> Advanced >> Multirom >> Configure Autoboot >> Select "Disable" & You will not see that Boot menu during startup.